# Difference between print and click.echo in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface

I am creating CLI app for Unix terminal using ***click*** module. So I see two ways how I can display data:
`print(data)` and `click.echo(data)`

What is difference between them and what should I use?

Comment: http://click.pocoo.org/5/quickstart/#echoing

Comment: It contains [*more options*](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/master/click/utils.py#L167)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please, read at least quickstart of library before using it. The answer is in [the third part of quickstart](http://click.pocoo.org/5/quickstart/#echoing).
If you use click `click.echo()` is preferred because:

> Click attempts to support both Python 2 and Python 3 the same way and to be very robust even when the environment is misconfigured. Click wants to be functional at least on a basic level even if everything is completely broken.
>
> What this means is that the echo() function applies some error correction in case the terminal is misconfigured instead of dying with an UnicodeError.
>
> As an added benefit, starting with Click 2.0, the echo function also has good support for ANSI colors. It will automatically strip ANSI codes if the output stream is a file and if colorama is supported, ANSI colors will also work on Windows. See ANSI Colors for more information.
>
> If you don’t need this, you can also use the print() construct / function.

Comment: I find that the source code of `click.echo` is quite clear.
1. it use util function from `click._compat`, which works like `six`, to make sure the library get support by both python2 & 3.
2. it works no matter the message is bytes or string.
3. color styling.
Here's the source [code](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/4da5e93cede17262424671208799bc6921dcfa36/click/utils.py#L167)